# need to convert multi select model to text area model in html, in Angularjs application

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

In my angularjs application, I am using multi select dropdown and its model is coming as follows :

```
$scope.selectedValues = [{"id":2,"name":"Automatic"},{"id":4,"name":"Manual"}];
```

and this model is nicely getting displayed. There is no problem in that. Now during view application stage, I need to hide this multi select drop down and need to show the all names in   `$scope.selectedValues` in text area. Without doing the manipulations in controller to get the model value for the text area, is it possible to extract names from `$scope.selectedValues` and display them as space separated values from html itself?

```
<textarea class="form-control" ng-model="allInsurancesNames" ng-if="needToDisbleMutiSelectDrpDown"></textarea>
```

Here the model `allInsurancesNames` should contain all names as space separated from model `selectedValues`. We can do any thing in html like using ng-repeats, or expressions, etc, whatever is needed to achieve this, but  `allInsurancesNames` should not be populated from  `$scope.selectedValues` in controller.

Comment: Do you have flexibility to create a function in the controller and use that in the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

If you can create a function inside your controller, you can do something like this:

```
$scope.mapFunct= function(value){
  return value.name;   
};
```

And

```
<div ng-controller="ctrl" ng-init="allInsurancesNames=selectedValues.map(mapFunct).join(' ')">
```

[Working Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/SUrGie4JMv6ZZ1vYhUnY)